# How to run npx Node.Js command on windows

Tags: node.js

I need to run the following command:

```
$ npx cubejs-cli create <project name> -d <database type>
```

I have installed node.Js on my windows machine.

I launch the c:\nodejs\node.exe and a console windows opens up.

I paste the command in the command line like this:

```
> $ npx cubejs-cli create trafficninja -d mssql
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    $ npx cubejs-cli create trafficninja -d mssql
      ^^^
```

Can someone advise how can I fix this issue?

Comment: npx is available with npm5.2+ check npm or node version

Comment: @TusharMistry I just installed the latest version of node, do you think that something was not enough?

Comment: Note that the `$` in tutorials denotes a shell prompt. It's not supposed to be copied verbatim, it means that the following command (without `$`) is to be run in a shell, in particular a bash-like Linux shell like Git Bash (although _this_ command works in cmd too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npx` is a feature with node that runs separate from the actual node executable.

So to solve your issue, open a normal command prompt window. Type the following

```
npx --v
```

Be sure you don't run this command *after* opening the node.exe executable CLI. Run it in a fresh command prompt window.

This will tell you if npx is intalled, and if so, what version you are running.

If you're still seeing the npx isn't recognized, navigate to the nodejs installation, typicall here:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

You should see a file called **npx** inside.

From here, copy the path and change directory in the console to this location with the following command:

```
cd C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

After that, type the npx commmand:

```
npx --v
```

If this works, then your installation is good, but for some reason the environment variables didn't assign during installation.

Comment: @realPro Then the problem is your environment variables not being populated for some reason. Please see edits to my answer.

Comment: As @CherryDT stated, restarting your machine may fix the environment variables.

Comment: My mistake, I run the ver command on my local PC instead of the AWS VM.

Comment: @realPro Node is amazing, stick with it my friend! You'll learn to love it.